# How to replace __prepare__ for metaclass in python 2

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, metaclass

I need to convert some code from python 3 to python 2. I have a metaclass where the `__prepare__` method sets up a function in the class dict. I tried to translate to a `__new__` method but I am unable to set up the `SET_DEFAULTS` function. Is that possible ?

I have a `NameError: name 'SET_DEFAULTS'` at initialization

```
class UazeMessageMeta (type):

    @staticmethod
    def __prepare__(name, bases, **kwargs):
        d = {}
        for b in bases: 
            if 'DEFAULT_VALUES' in dir(b):
                d.update(b.DEFAULT_VALUES)
        return { 
            'SET_DEFAULTS' : lambda **kwargs : d.update(kwargs),
            'DEFAULT_VALUES' : d
        }

class UazeMessage (bytearray):
    """
    A basic message (header only).  This class also provides the
    base behavior for all messages.
    """
    # gp test py27 -----------------
    __metaclass__ = UazeMessageMeta 

    # ------------

    priority    = MessageField(0,  1,  Priority)
    sequence    = MessageField(1,  7,  FieldType.UNSIGNED)
    readWrite   = MessageField(8,  1,  ReadWriteFlag)
    ack         = MessageField(9,  2,  Ack)
    channel     = MessageField(11, 2,  FieldType.UNSIGNED)
    category    = MessageField(13, 3,  Category)
    item        = MessageField(16, 8,  FieldType.UNSIGNED)

    DEFAULT_SIZE = 3

    def __init__(self, init=0, setdefaults=None, **kwargs):
        # If init is still or None, initialize the size of the message
        # using the default size provided in the class.
        if init == None or init == 0: 
            init = type(self).DEFAULT_SIZE
        super(UrmpMessage,self).__init__(init)
        # Set any default or provided fields.
        initval = {}
        if (isinstance(init, int) and setdefaults != False) or \
           (setdefaults == True):
            initval = dict(self.DEFAULT_VALUES)
        initval.update(kwargs)
        for key, value in initval.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)

class ResetBase (UazeMessage):
    """Reset response/request structure."""

    resetType = MessageField(24, 8, ResetType)

    SET_DEFAULTS(
        category  = Category.OPERATION,
        resetType = ResetType.SOFT,
        item      = 0)

    DEFAULT_SIZE = 4
```

Comment: Please review the indentation in your post; it matters in Python.

Comment: I have updated, sorry about the inconvenience

Comment: It seems that at least one class is missing there. Please give a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ordinarily, you can't do that. 
The introduction of `__prepare__` is a fundamental change in Python3, which allows the customization of the namespace where a class body itself is parsed.

I believe the main motivation doing that was to provide a way to replace the local namespace inside a class body with an OrderedDict, so that the class initialization (in the metaclass `__new__` or `__init__` methods) could benefit from the declaration order of methods and attributes inside the class body. It should be considered that as of Python 3.6 (final version due this week), an ordered dictionary is used by default in the class body, and a metaclass is no longer necessary for that.

The `__prepare__` mechanism is way more flexible than that, and in a simpler use, allow one to simply pre-populate the class body dictionary with predetermined values.  That is what your project do.

However, since this code does not need an special dictionary class, and just pre-populate an ordinary dictionary, all you need to do is to write an ordinary function that takes in a dictionary and base classes as parameters, and fills in that dictionary according to the existing code in the `__prepare__` method. Then, call that function in the beggining of a class body, passing in the dictionary returned by the `locals()`  call as parameter. That is it: the class body namespace can be pre-filled in the sameway.

```
def prepare(bases, dct):
    for base in bases:
        dct["special_attribute"] = {}
        if "special_attribute" in base.__dict__:
            dct["special_attribute" ].update(base.__dict__["special_attribute"])
     ...

class MyClass(bytearray):
    prepare((bytearray,), locals())
    ...
```

All that said, I really advise you to try if possible NOT to backport a project to Python2 at this point in time - it will just complicate your codebase - and give up using new features in a consistent way (for example, this tip above instead of `__prepare__` )

Comment: Thanks for your explanation - it is was that I was looking for. I will try to make the project python 2 and 3 compatible - but it can be tricky when it comes to the metaclass

Comment: It should be noted that the default dictionary being ordered in Python 3.6 is not necessarily going to be true for Python 3.6+ *yet*.  Official statements have been this is a neat feature that isn't necessarily going to be supported in the future.  In others words, Programmer Beware.

Comment: While the default ordering of literal dict is still being discussed, ordering within the class body is a separate issue (even though at implementation level they are intermixed). Order within the class body declaration of attributes is defined in PEP 520 and is part of the language spec now.